# Is it possible to animate the camera to several destinations

Tags: android, google-maps, android-camera

Is it possible to move the google maps camera to several locations? e.g. moving to place A, then to place B, etc.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Accomplish this you need to use the GoogleMap.animateCamera() function and use with it GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() with onFinish() function to know when the moving animation is finished so you can animate to the next one.
Animate from Place to place example code:

```
// The below Coordinates numbers are just for the demo
LatLng placeALatLng = new LatLng(31.11, 23.8859);
LatLng placeBLatLng = new LatLng(23.8859, 11.4211);
LatLng placeCALatLng = new LatLng(11.4211, 23.8859);

private ArrayList<LatLng> places = new ArrayList<>();

int count = 0;

private void startAnimating(){
    places.add(placeALatLng);
    places.add(placeBLatLng);
    places.add(placeCALatLng);

    animateToNextPlace();
}

private void animateToNextPlace(){
    if(count >= places.size()){
        return;
    }

    animateCameraToLocation(places.get(count));

    count++;
}



private void animateCameraToLocation(LatLng placeLatLng){
    final int zoom = 12;
    final int duration = 1000; // 1 second
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(placeLatLng, zoom), duration, new  GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //Animate to next Location
            animateToNextPlace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }
    });
}
```

Or if you want to simply Move Camera without duration and without on finish moving to next place use the below:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(placeA.getLatitude(), placeA.getLongitude()))
                            .zoom(15)
                            .build();
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: Yes, but I first want to move it to A and then to B. It should move to A and then automatically to B.

Comment: Please check the updated answer: Move to a place than after the map moving animation is done move to the next one.
Just add your own Coordinate to the 3 points and call the function startAnimating()
Good luck

Comment: @Leon if you need any clarification for the answer update, please let me know.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! :-)